# HammerJS stopped working after updating to Angular 9

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I've recently updated my web app from Angular 8 to Angular 9. I noticed that HammerJS is not working properly anymore. After a few search on Google, I rapidly found out I needed to add HammerModule as part 
of my 'imports' statement in 'app.module.ts', as stated here:

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/v9-hammerjs-migration.md

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HammerModule,
    ...
]
```

I followed the guidelines and removed the dependency from my 'package.json' file and the side-effect import of HammerJS in my main.ts file.

Now when I'm running my app, I get these errors:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or did I forget something? I've been searching for a while now and haven't found any solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but not sure if it's the best one. I still import the HammerModule in my 'app.module.ts' but I also put back the side-effect import of 'hammerjs', which the documentation says shouldn't be required.

Inside my main.ts:

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Hope this can help someone or that the Angular team will fix this issue eventually.